# inner join to count rows and order

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I'm trying to read some things about some user, but, I execute 3 queries to count "FOLLOWERS" and "LINKS", and I know that is possible do it with one query, using inner join, etc. I don't know how to make this, someone can help me?

I'm brazillian, sorry for the bad english.

```
$Read = new Read();
$Read->FullRead("SELECT AUTHORS_NAME, AUTHORS_LASTNAME, AUTHORS_PHOTO, AUTHORS_FRIENDLY_URL, AUTHORS_ID FROM AUTHORS");

if ($Read->getResult()):
    foreach ($Read->getResult() as $AUTHORS):
        extract($AUTHORS);

        $COUNT = 0;
        $READ_FOLLOWER = new Read();
        $READ_FOLLOWER->FullRead("SELECT AUTHORS_ID FROM FOLLOWERS WHERE AUTHORS_ID = {$AUTHORS_ID}");
        if ($READ_FOLLOWER->getResult()):
            foreach ($READ_FOLLOWER->getResult() as $READ_FOLLOWER_ITEM):
                $COUNT++;
            endforeach;
        endif;

        $LINK_COUNT = 0;
        $READ_LINKS = new Read();
        $READ_LINKS->FullRead("SELECT LINK_AUTHORS FROM LINKS WHERE LINK_AUTHORS = {$AUTHORS_ID}");
        if ($READ_LINKS->getResult()):
            foreach ($READ_LINKS->getResult() as $READ_LINKS_ITEM):
                $LINK_COUNT++;
            endforeach;
        endif;

        //ECHO ON ALL VARIABLES

    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Please remove the incorrect tag.

Comment: You might be interesting in the Portuguese version of this site http://pt.stackoverflow.com/.  In addition, you should fix the tags -- Oracle and MySQL are very different databases.

Comment: If you just want to get a count of matching rows, use `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of a loop that reads each row.

Answer (score 1):

With one query, you can try this:

```
SELECT A.AUTHORS_NAME, A.AUTHORS_LASTNAME, A.AUTHORS_PHOTO, A.AUTHORS_FRIENDLY_URL, A.AUTHORS_ID,
   COALESCE(T1.CNT, 0) AS FOLLOWERS_CNT,
   COALESCE(T2.CNT, 0) AS LINKS_CNT
FROM AUTHORS A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT AUTHORS_ID, COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM FOLLOWERS GROUP BY AUTHORS_ID
) T1 ON A.AUTHORS_ID = T1.AUTHORS_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT LINK_AUTHORS, COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM LINKS GROUP BY LINK_AUTHORS
) T2 ON A.AUTHORS_ID = T2.LINK_AUTHORS
ORDER BY T1.CNT, T2.CNT DESC
```

Comment: QLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 918 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148).

Comment: @HalyssonTevesDosSantos Could you please run this query in Oracle CLI and check if this error still exists or not?

Comment: ORA-00918: coluna definida de maneira ambígua
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 1 Coluna: 77

Comment: Thank you, working! Do you want get some money helping me to finish my social network? It is 90% complete, I just need to correct some bugs, and functions, we can do it by teamviewer. I pay by paypal, if you got interest, please send me your e-mail...

Comment: How I can order by "FOLLOWERS_CNT,LINKS_CNT DESC"? Thank you.

Comment: @HalyssonTevesDosSantos Sure, I can help you. And check my answer again. tinyfatzi@gmail.com

Comment: The order by don't works... Check the results: uploaddeimagens DOT com DOT br/images/000/663/004/full/orderbe.png?1468297573

Comment: @HalyssonTevesDosSantos Cause it has `null` value, I use `coalesce` to compute `null` as 0, check the answer please.

Comment: Results: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/da-png--25. Query: SELECT A.PAGE_PHOTO, A.PAGE_FRIENDLY_URL, A.PAGE_NAME, A.PAGE_ID,
   COALESCE(T1.CNT, 0) AS FOLLOWERS_CNT,
   COALESCE(T2.CNT, 0) AS LINKS_CNT
FROM PAGES A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT AUTHORS_ID, COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM FOLLOWERS GROUP BY AUTHORS_ID
) T1 ON A.PAGE_ID = T1.AUTHORS_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT LINK_PAGE_ID, COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM LINKS GROUP BY LINK_PAGE_ID
) T2 ON A.PAGE_ID = T2.LINK_PAGE_ID ORDER BY T1.CNT, T2.CNT DESC

Comment: @HalyssonTevesDosSantos What is your expected result?

Comment: I want to add the two results and order the result added. Example: LINK_CNT (5) FOLLOWERS_CNT + (5) = 10
LINK_CNT (4) + FOLLOWERS_CNT (4) = 8
LINK_CNT (2) + FOLLOWERS_CNT (2) = 4

Comment: Would you please add your expected result in you question?

Answer (score 0):

Use sub query for this, in a single row you can get the total rows of followers and links

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT SUM(B.AUTHORS_ID) FROM FOLLOWERS B WHERE A.AUTHORS_ID=B.AUTHORS_ID) FOLLOWERS, 
    (SELECT SUM(C.AUTHORS_ID) FROM LINKS C WHERE A.AUTHORS_ID=c.AUTHORS_ID) LINKS  
FROM AUTHORS A
```